# Magento2 - How can I setup Vue StoreFront in my local Magento2.4 version

Tags: magento2, ubuntu, vue-storefront, vue

How can I setup Vue StoreFront in my local Magento2.4 version

I have followed below steps
https://docs.vuestorefront.io/guide/cookbook/setup.html#_2-recipe-2

From where can I get consumer key, consumer secret, access token and token secret ?

Anyone have any idea please suggest or guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your magento's admin panel go to,
`Store > Extensions > Integrations.`

From there add new integration.
Select APIs which you want to permit for vue storefront.
Than save those permissions and activate it.

After activation you'll get your access tokens.

Comment: Is there any steps for this ?

Comment: Have you installed the module for vue storefront integration on magento yet? Because the things that I have mentioned in my comment can only be done after installing that integration module.

Comment: No, I didn't installed any module yet

Comment: There is already I can see under System -> Extension -> Integrations

Comment: I have setup with Magento2 but can't see my categories in navigations

Comment: If you found my answer usefull in getting your access tokens than mark this answer correct and ask this "I have setup with Magento2 but can't see my categories in navigations" in a separate question. Thanks